# Microsoft Azure appending extra query string to urls with query strings

Tags: django, iis, azure, cgi, fastcgi

In deploying a version of the Django website I'm working on to Microsoft's Azure service, I added a page which takes a query string like

```
http://<my_site_name>.azurewebsites.net/security/user/?username=<some_username>&password=<some_password>
```

However, I was getting 404 responses to this URL. So I turned on Django's Debug flag and the page I get returned said:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://<my_site_name>.azurewebsites.net/security/user/?username=<some_username>&password=<some_password>?username=<some_username>&password=<some_password>


Using the `URLconf` defined in `<my_project_name>.urls`, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

^$
^security/ ^user/$
^account/
^admin/
^api/

The current URL, `security/user/?username=<some_username>&password=<some_password>`, didn't match any of these.
```

So it seems to be appending the query string onto the end of the url that already has the same query string. I have the site running on my local machine and on an iis server on my internal network which I'm using for staging before pushing to Azure. Neither of these site deployments do this, so this seems to be something specific to Azure.

Is there something I need to set in the Azure website management interface to prevent it from modifying URLs with query strings? Is there something I'm doing wrong with regards to using query strings with Azure?

Comment: I found another question that seems very similar to mine: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12698625/query-string-get-appened-more-than-once But I'm not sure how to implement the suggested solution on Azure. Not the part about rewriting to force https, just the part that prevents the query string doubling.

Comment: Looking into it further, I've tracked the problem down to the path_info variable. I'm using the WSGIHandler provided by Django using get_wsgi_application() in Azure as the WSGI_HANDLER app setting as this tutorial indicates I should be doing: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/python/tutorials/web-sites-with-django/ . Looking at the information that handler receives from the environment variables though, it seems as though QUERY_STRING is empty and PATH_INFO has the full url + query string. Which seems to be causing my issues. Not sure if it's a problem with fastcgi or iis though.

Comment: Correction to the above comment. QUERY_STRING isn't empty. That was my fault in trying to get rid of the double query strings using url rewriting I removed the query string via Web.config file. The root of the issue now is just that PATH_INFO contains the query string and the Django WSGI handler is not expecting it to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In speaking to the providers of wfastcgi.py they told me it may be an issue with wfastcgi.py that is causing this problem. While they look into it they gave me a work around that fixes the issue.

Download the latest copy of wfastcgi.py from http://pytools.codeplex.com/releases

In that file find this part of the code:

```
if 'HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_URL' in record.params:
    # We've been re-written for shared FastCGI hosting, send the original URL as the PATH_INFO.
    record.params['PATH_INFO'] = record.params['HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_URL']
```

And add right below it (still part of the if block):

```
# PATH_INFO is not supposed to include the query parameters, so remove them
record.params['PATH_INFO'] = record.params['PATH_INFO'].split('?')[0]
```

Then, upload/deploy this modified file to the Azure site (either use the ftp to put it somewhere or add it to your site deployment. I'm deploying it so that if I need to modify it further its versioned and backed up.

In the Azure management page for the site, go to the site's configure page and change the handler mapping to point to the modified wfastcgi.py file and save the configuration.

i.e. my handler used to be the default D:\python27\scripts\wfastcgi.py. Since I deployed my modified file, the handler path is now: D:\home\site\wwwroot\wfastcgi.py

I also restarted the site, but you may not have to.

This modified script should now strip the query string from PATH_INFO, and urls with query strings should work. I'll be using this until I hear from the wfastcgi.py devs that the default wfastcgi.py file in the Python27 install has been fixed/replaced.